# Colored Points Disappearing When Creating an Animation in R using Plotly

Tags: r, animation, plotly

I'm trying to create an animation in R using `plotly` where a point can change colors based on its state at the current time.  Each point can transition from one phase to another at any time, and I think `plotly` is losing track of the point transitions due to the changing of colors.

In the code below, you'll see that the animation is smooth without any colors. But when the colors are included in the plot, the points start misbehaving during the animation - either they get stuck, they disappear, or they jump all over the plot.

Do you have any suggestions to fix this, or perhaps an alternate way to animate a shifting-state in R?

```
library(plotly)

plot_colors <- c(red = "red", gray = "gray")

df <- 
  data.frame(step = rep(1:10, 2),
             id   = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10)),
             x    = c(1:10, 1:10),
             y    = c(1:10, 10:1),
             col  = sample(c("red", "gray"), 20, replace = TRUE)) 

# This animation is smooth  
df %>% plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, frame = ~step, mode = "markers", type = "scatter")

# This animation has the points jumping all over the screen, and points disappear
df %>% plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, frame = ~step, color = ~col, 
               colors = plot_colors, mode = "markers", type = "scatter")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this passing the color argument as follows `marker = list(color = ~col)`

```
df %>% plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, frame = ~step,
               marker = list(color = ~col),
                 mode = "markers", type = "scatter")
```

> Increasing the marker size and adding line will make it easier to see the color change during animation

```
df %>% plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, frame = ~step, marker = list(color = ~col, size = 25, line = list(color = 'black',width = 5)),
               mode = "markers", type = "scatter")
```